# Create folder on OS X

Tags: java, macos, filesystems, classnotfound, create-directory

I have one code to create Folder into the Mac OS

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 *
 * @author kishan
 */
public class CreatingMacFile {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        boolean check = new CreatingMacFile().makefile();
        if (check) {
            System.out.println("file created");
        }else{
            System.out.println("file is not created");
        }
    }


    public boolean makefile() {
        try {

            String resource = CreatingMacFile.class.getName().replace(".", File.separator) + ".class";
            URL fileURL = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(resource);

            String path = new File(fileURL.toURI()).getParent();
            System.out.println("this is path that we getting: "+path);
            String mySubFolder = "subFolder";
            File newDir = new File(path + File.separator + mySubFolder);

            System.out.println("File Path: "+newDir.getAbsolutePath());

            boolean success = newDir.mkdir();

            if (success) {
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

but i am getting error of noClassFound

what i am missing?

stacktrace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: CreatingMacFile
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CreatingMacFile
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace please?

Comment: Its just that Same class not found what i execute

Comment: Can you please post it? Likely there is some useful information on the exception you are getting

Comment: So you're trying to create a folder at "/com/package/subpackage/NameOfYourClass/"?

Comment: hmm cant it be created.?

Comment: Sure, you can. But it'll probably raise a `SecurityException` because of the file system structure. Mind if I ask why you need it there, and not at, eg. "**/tmp**/com/package/subpackage/NameOfYourClass/"?

Comment: Sorry i did not got u @okiharaherbst can u just edit code and post it?

Comment: @okiharaherbst can u just give simple edit of that?

Comment: @Krishna see my answer below

Comment: @okiharaherbst sorry for not saying but its working in windows and ubuntu but just not working in Mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Class<?> c = ...
File file = new File("/tmp/", c.getName().replaceAll("\\.", File.separator));
file.mkdirs();
```

Note the `mkdirs()` method (with an ending `s`). HTH.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand your last comment.

Comment: its creating folder and now if i want to create file then?

Comment: @Krishna if you want to create a file, just do `File newFile = new File(file, "somefile")` and don't forget to do `file.createNewFile()`. HTH